# Nintex forms 2013: issue when use DateTime control with IE8

Tags: datetime, internet-explorer-8

I use Nintex forms 2013.
When open a form contains DateTime control on IE8, I got an error: "NWF.Filler.Ribbon is null or not object". And then, when click any button,  it does not fire event.

Note: IE9 or above work well.

Any one has same problem? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?